# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. - NodeJS

Tags: node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var http = require('http');

router.get('*', function(req, res, next) {

    http.get("http://steamcommunity.com/id/reminant/inventory/json/730/2", 
        function (response) {
            response.on('data', function (data) {
                var stringData = data.toString();
                console.log(stringData);
                res.render('index', { "data": stringData });
         });
    }).on('error', function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Console:

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (e:\Users\Documents\Repositories\CSGOTest\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (e:\Users\Documents\Repositories\CSGOTest\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:551:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (e:\Users\Documents\Repositories\CSGOTest\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:138:14)
    at done (e:\Users\Documents\Repositories\CSGOTest\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:957:10)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (e:\Users\Documents\Repositories\CSGOTest\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:374:12)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (e:\Users\Documents\Repositories\CSGOTest\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:417:11)
    at View.render (e:\Users\Documents\Repositories\CSGOTest\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
    at tryRender (e:\Users\Documents\Repositories\CSGOTest\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (e:\Users\Documents\Repositories\CSGOTest\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:591:3)`

Comment: This has been answered already: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should write like this:

```
var buffers = [];
var size = 0;
response.on('data', function (data) {
    buffers.push(data);
    size += data.length;
});
res.render('index', {data: Buffer.concat(buffers, size).toString()});
```

Comment: That fixed the error, but the array is empty when I try to concat it.

Comment: Sorry, the last statement should like this: `res.on('end', function () {res.render('index', {data: Buffer.concat(buffers, size).toString()});})`

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate response to a string and call render in end handler

```
var stringData = '';
response.on('data', function(data) {
    stringData += data.toString();
}

response.on('end', function() {
    res.render('index', { "data": stringData });
}
```